# Converting 3 useful methods from AS3 to C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

The following are 3 useful methods I almost always use in my AS3 projects. I'd like to convert to C# for use in my Unity projects. Can any C#-Unity experts help?

```
public function normalize(value:Number, minimum:Number, maximum:Number):Number
{
return (value - minimum) / (maximum - minimum);
}

public function interpolate(normValue:Number, minimum:Number, maximum:Number):Number
{
return minimum + (maximum - minimum) * normValue;
}

public function map(value:Number, min1:Number, max1:Number, min2:Number, max2:Number):Number
{
return interpolate( normalize(value, min1, max1), min2, max2);
}
```

Comment: SO isn't a code conversion service. That said, change "Number" to double and rewrite the function definitions in C# syntax. Thats it!

Comment: are you telling me that you can't read the existing code and convert it to a method in C# come on this is actually staring you right in the face for example the first on would be 

`public Int normalize(int value, int minimum, int maximum)
{
   return "your code or equation
}`

Comment: read a book or do a simple google search on how to declare a procedure / method in `C#` show more effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are using no class members, they can be declared as static methods.  If these are integers, then use `int` otherwise you could use `float` or `double` depending on what you are passing.

```
public class MathHelpers {
             // int return type here
  public static int Normalize(int value, int minimum, int maximum)
  {
    return (value - minimum) / (maximum - minimum);
  }

}
```

Hopefully from that you can easily figure out how to convert the others.